# Adding Swashbuckle to the project causes error "Make sure that controller has a parameterless public constructor"

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, swashbuckle

I have a project using OWIN. The whole solution consists of five parts:

1. Web application
2. Core
3. Infrastructure
4. WebApi
5. Tests

The project works well.

Recently, I planned to put swagger in my project. After some research, I decided to use Swashbuckle. https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#custom-routes

I followed its tutorial by adding the following code to my Startup.cs:

```
HttpConfiguration Config = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(Config);
Config.EnableSwagger((c) =>
{
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Flynn Forms");
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
}).EnableSwaggerUi();
app.UseWebApi(Config);
```

Then, I did my API documentation at http://localhost:22391/swagger/ui/index. However, all my APIs stopped working. I got errors of my controllers such as:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'FormTemplateController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

I did not have a parameterless constructor... But it worked well before adding the Swashbuckle. I googled this error, someone suggested that just adding a parameterless constructor will solve this error. So my controller became:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/develop")]
public class FormTemplateController : ApiController
{
    private IFormTemplateService formTemplateService;
    public FormTemplateController()
    {
    }

    public FormTemplateController(IFormTemplateService formTemplateService)
    {
        this.formTemplateService = formTemplateService;
    }
    [Route("form/{formId}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public FormTemplateEntity GetActiveFormTemplateByformId(string formId)
    {
        FormTemplateEntity formTemplate = formTemplateService.GetActiveFormTemplateEntityByFormId(formId);
        return formTemplate;
    }
    ....(different APIs)
}
```

The error did has gone. But I am now getting a new error indicating that formTemplateService is null.

I am using Castle Windsor as Inversion of Control container for my project. Does Swashbuckle have some conflicts with Castle Windsor? Does anyone have same issue and get a solution? I am not sure if I have provided enough background information. If you need more information, please leave them in the comments.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like your IoC is not set up correctly?

Comment: But my project worked well before adding the Swashbuckle. If my IoC is not set up correctly, how did my project work? @MarkC.

Answer (score 1):

After trying different methods, I found the following works. 
At first, I put the codes:

```
HttpConfiguration Config = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(Config);
Config.EnableSwagger((c) =>
{
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Flynn Forms");
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
}).EnableSwaggerUi();
app.UseWebApi(Config);
```

in Startup.cs cause I thought this is the entrance of my solution.
Then, I notice in my WebApi part, I have a file called WebApiConfig.cs which configs the instance of HttpConfiguration as well. So I moved codes to this file. (Because there has already been an instance of HttpConfiguration there, you don't have to create it again.) Just put the following codes there:

```
Config.EnableSwagger((c) =>
{
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Flynn Forms");
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
}).EnableSwaggerUi();
```

The problem got solved.